# Unable to set Array elements to TextView using using Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, textview

I have seven **TextViews** and seven elements in an array . Now , I want to set these array elements in seven different TextViews. But , my app gets stopped when this Activity opens.

Here is my Activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".ProfileActivity">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/main_app_bar_layout" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_name_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="26sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_email_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:text="Email"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_id_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:text="ID"
    android:textColor="@color/spots_dialog_color"
    android:textSize="24sp" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="223dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_invite_code1"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_invite_code2"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_invite_code3"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_invite_code4"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_invite_code5"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="e"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_invite_code6"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="r"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_invite_code7"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="s"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is Activity.java

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// toolbar instance
private Toolbar mToolbar;
RelativeLayout rootLayout;

//Array for invite code digits
public char inviteArray[] = new char[7];

// Text view Instances
private TextView mUserConnectionId;
private TextView mProfileUsernameView;
private TextView mProfileEmailView;
public TextView mInviteCodetext1;
public TextView mInviteCodetext2;
public TextView mInviteCodetext3;
public TextView mInviteCodetext4;
public TextView mInviteCodetext5;
public TextView mInviteCodetext6;
public TextView mInviteCodetext7;

TextView []  inviteTextView = { mInviteCodetext1 ,
                                mInviteCodetext2 ,
                                mInviteCodetext3 ,
                                mInviteCodetext4 ,
                                mInviteCodetext5 ,
                                mInviteCodetext6 ,
                                mInviteCodetext7 };

//Firebase
private DatabaseReference mUserDataBaseRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //set contentView
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Arkhip_font.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build()
    );

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    //Custom Toolbar
    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar()
            .setTitle("Profile");
    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mUserConnectionId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_id_text);
    mProfileUsernameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_name_view);
    mProfileEmailView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_email_view);

    //Invite code Text view
    mInviteCodetext1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_invite_code1);
    mInviteCodetext2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_invite_code2);
    mInviteCodetext3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_invite_code3);
    mInviteCodetext4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_invite_code4);
    mInviteCodetext5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_invite_code5);
    mInviteCodetext6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_invite_code6);
    mInviteCodetext7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_invite_code7);

    mInviteCodetext1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext_background));
    mInviteCodetext2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext_background));
    mInviteCodetext3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext_background));
    mInviteCodetext4.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext_background));
    mInviteCodetext5.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext_background));
    mInviteCodetext6.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext_background));
    mInviteCodetext7.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext_background));

}   

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

     mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        mUserDataBaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

    }
    mUserDataBaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String username = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            String email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
            String inviteCode = dataSnapshot.child("uniqueID").getValue().toString();

            mUserConnectionId.setText(inviteCode);
            mProfileUsernameView.setText(username);
            mProfileEmailView.setText(email);

            for (int i = 0; i < inviteCode.length(); ++i) {
                inviteArray[i] = inviteCode.charAt(i); // This array giving me correct result
            }

            for (int i=0 ; i<inviteArray.length; ++i){
                inviteTextView[i].setText(inviteArray[i]);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

My logact is giving these errors :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.ankit.controlchild.ProfileActivity$1.onDataChange(ProfileActivity.java:134)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.to.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.vj.zzHX(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here . And , Is there any better way of doing this.

Comment: used recyclerview or listview for above.

Comment: post your error log.

Comment: what value in `inviteCode ` string?

Comment: try `invitetextView[i].setText(inviteArray[I]+"");`

Comment: post-LogCat report so we can find your what exactly you doing wrong

Comment: @RahulChokshi ,I have posted my logcat report here , please check

Comment: @Ankitpareek do you really expect help when you keep editing and posting new fragments of your code that weren't there 2 mins ago? What else are you hiding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that this line:

```
String inviteCode = dataSnapshot.child("uniqueID").getValue().toString();
```

will return a string that has exactly 7 chars?  
If not and the length of `inviteCode` is less than 7 then this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < inviteCode.length(); ++i) {
    inviteArray[i] = inviteCode.charAt(i);
}
```

will leave 1 or more elements of `inviteArray` uninitialized so they're null and then in this loop:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<inviteArray.length; ++i){
    inviteTextView[i].setText(inviteArray[i]);
}
```

you will get a `NPE` and the app will crash.

The app would crash anyway because `inviteArray[i]` is of type `char`, so replace that last loop with this:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<inviteArray.length; ++i){
    inviteTextView[i].setText("" + inviteArray[i]);
}
```

Edit:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<inviteArray.length; ++i){
    try {
        inviteTextView[i].setText("" + inviteArray[i]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: it returns only 7 character string from database . I replaced setText with setText(""+inviteArray[i])  , but same error . If i manually set like setText(""+inviteArray[0]) , setText(""+inviteArray[1])....... then there is no error. Please Explain

Comment: @Ankitpareek this is the proof that it does **not** return 7 chars. Use the last loop in my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public char inviteArray[] = new char[6]; // Array for invite code digits
```

I think, it may due to array index value error.
the two array `length()` are not same.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i = 0; i < inviteArray.lenght(); ++i){
          invitetextView[i].setText(inviteArray[i]);
        }
```

here replace ++i with i++ also check the array length is same or not

Answer (score 0):

i have tested your code it seems right the problem you are facing is due to error in class structure. Place your addListner inside `onStart()` method
as

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mUserDataBaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        String inviteCode = dataSnapshot.child("WYZ").getValue().toString();

        mUserConnectionId.setText(inviteCode);


        for (int i = 0; i < inviteCode.length(); i++) {
            inviteArray[i] = inviteCode.charAt(i); // This array giving me correct result
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < inviteArray.lenght() && i < invitetextview.lenght(); i++){ // this adding one more condition eliminate your nullPointerException
          invitetextView[i].setText(inviteArray[i]);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
}
```

you are using it out side any method thats why your app is crashing

hope it is helping

Comment: Thanks @faiizi awan but , it is not working , giving same error . I am posting my logcat errors here , i think it helps to solve my problem

Comment: againg you are trying to initialize your widget outside the onCreate method or you should make a constructor and initialize your text widget there

Comment: sorry i have not updated my source code with this method in on onStart() , but error remains same

Answer (score 0):

Your logs are suggesting that textviews are null.

Which may be because method **mUserDataBaseRef.addValueEventListener()** is getting called before textview initialisation.

**Solution :**

1 : Check if textview is null before putting data. Then wait for sometime and hope that it happens. Then do it. (Maybe a handler will help.)

2 : Put  **mUserDataBaseRef.addValueEventListener()** in onStart.

p.s. I would prefer 2nd option.